# Размещение элементов на странице

Tags: html, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Не очень часто приходилось работать с asp разметкой. Есть на форме lable, после него следом dropdownlist и всё это в td  находиться. Строками ниже добавляю таблицу. Но на странице она отображается на следующей строчке. Как сделать так что бы она выровнялась с лейблом и дроп дауном?

```html
<tr id="tr_Def" runat="server">
  <td style="padding-bottom: 15px; text-align: center;" align="center">
    <table class="textBlue" style="font-size: 11pt">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Расположение дефекта (количество)
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="tbDefectCount" runat="server" SkinID="sktxt_Manual" TabIndex="71" Width="40px" onkeypress="MaskCheck('dd')" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="tbDefectCount_TextChanged" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Table runat="server" ID="TableDefects" GridLines="Both" Width="98%" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" BorderWidth="2px" BorderStyle="Groove" Style="display: block">
      <asp:TableRow>
      </asp:TableRow>
      <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow2" runat="server" Style="color: #41519A; text-align: center;
                                        font-family: verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: small">
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell5" runat="server" SkinID="sktc_Manual2" Style="width: 30%" RowSpan="2">Код - Наименование</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell6" runat="server" SkinID="sktc_Manual2" ColumnSpan="3">Расположение дефекта, мм</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell7" runat="server" SkinID="sktc_Manual2" ColumnSpan="2">Размер дефекта, мм</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell8" runat="server" SkinID="sktc_Manual2" RowSpan="2">Расположение</asp:TableCell>
      </asp:TableHeaderRow>
      <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow3" runat="server" Style="color: #41519A; text-align: center;
                                        font-family: verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: small">
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell9" runat="server" SkinID="sktc_Manual2">Север</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell10" runat="server" SkinID="sktc_Manual2">Юг</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell11" runat="server" SkinID="sktc_Manual2">Координата по часам</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell12" runat="server" SkinID="sktc_Manual2">Длина</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell13" runat="server" SkinID="sktc_Manual2">Глубина</asp:TableCell>
      </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    </asp:Table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример вашего кода, так как по описанию нельзя однозначно судить каким именно образом вставлятся таблица (в тот же стобец или ту же строку той таблицы где lable и dropdownlist), и вообще table ли это. Желательнго еще пояснить как именно необходимо выровнять таблицу с остальными элементами - по центру, по краю.

Comment: @Uranus немножко разобрался как сделать. Теперь проблема в выравнивании в строку. Таблица завёрнута в td. И почему то на пол экрана встала. А мне нужно на весь что бы растянулась. Хотя на другой форме, эта же td вытянута на весь экран. Не пойму почему не получается так же. Код привожу в вопрос.